# AngularJS - Switch between items in ng repeat with ng click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a small JSON Object, with country and city.

The ng-repeat is calling the country. So I want now that when I click on a country item, that this item shows the city and with an other click its switching back to country.

I have two function, where i can switch the item from country to city, but i cannot switch back to the originally (country) one. How can i do that ?

My HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="test">

<div ng-repeat="module in values" ng-click="select? setSelected() : setSelected2();select = !select">
    {{module.country}}
</div>
```

and my `.js` file:

```
var app = angular.module('AngularApp', []);

app.controller('test', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.values = [
    {
        country: 'England',
        city: 'London',

    },
    {
        country: 'Spain',
        city: 'Madrid',
    }];


$scope.select = true;

$scope.setSelected = function() {

       $scope.values[this.$index].country = $scope.values[this.$index].city;           

    }

$scope.setSelected2 = function() {

       $scope.values[this.$index].country = $scope.values[this.$index].country;

    }

    return false;

}]);
```

Here is a plunker with my code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/MMqDXJFE9dUcWvuGKRDV?p=preview

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only for display purposes, this can help you, without the need of any Angular functions to be placed in the `.js` file:

```
<div ng-repeat="module in values" ng-click="select = !select">
    {{select ? module.city : module.country}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own model to store displayed value:

```
$scope.values = [
{
    country: 'England',
    city: 'London',
    showCountry: true
},
{
    country: 'Spain',
    city: 'Madrid',
    showCountry: true
}];



$scope.setSelected = function() {
   if ($scope.values[this.$index].showCountry)
   {
    $scope.values[this.$index].showCountry = false;
   } else {
    $scope.values[this.$index].showCountry = true;
   }
}

<div ng-repeat="module in values" ng-click="setSelected()">
  {{module.showCountry ? module.country : module.city}}
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/RsXRMKUETsw9aC0ozkr4?p=preview